# How to call a checked radio button using value in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a password generator while learning javascript. Is there a way to call the checked radio button using a value or do I switch to getElementbyId while calling.

My HTML body-

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Please select the type of Password you want to generate:</p>
  <form id="new-form">
    <input type="radio" id="wp" name="radio" class="redio" value="0" />
    <label for="wp">Weak Password</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="sp" name="radio" class="redio" value="1" />
    <label for="sp">Strong Password</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="ssp" name="radio" class="redio" value="2" />
    <label for="ssp">Super Strong Password</label>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Generate Password" />
  </form>
  <div id="display" type="text" readonly="true"></div>
</div>
```

My javascript-

```
class password{
    constructor(){
        this.ucl="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        this.lcl="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        this.num="1234567890"
        this.spc = "!@#$%^&*()"
    }
    weakpassword(){
        let arr = [this.ucl, this.lcl]
        let pass = ""
        for(let i=0;i<8;i++){
            let random1= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
            let random2= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr[random1].length)
            pass= pass + arr[random1][random2]
        }
        return pass
    }
    strongpassword(){
        let arr = [this.ucl, this.lcl, this.num]
        let pass = ""
        for(let i=0;i<14;i++){
            let random1= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
            let random2= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr[random1].length)
            pass= pass + arr[random1][random2]
        }
        return pass
    }
    superstrongpassword(){
        let arr = [this.ucl, this.lcl, this.num, this.spc]
        let pass = ""
        for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
            let random1= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
            let random2= Math.floor(Math.random()*arr[random1].length)
            pass= pass + arr[random1][random2]
        }
        return pass
    }
}

let display = document.getElementById("display");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let radio = document.getElementsByClassName("redio");

let a = new password()

btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let b;
    // if(document.getElementById('wp').checked){
    //     b= a.weakpassword()
    // }
    if(radio[0].checked){
        b= a.weakpassword()
    }
    else if(radio[1].checked){
        b= a.strongpassword()
    }
    else if(radio[2].checked){
        b= a.superstrongpassword()
    }
    display.value= b
})
```

Here, I am getting an error-

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

I'm trying to call the checked radio option value but getting an error 'Cannot read properties of null'.

Comment: Is your Javascript before or after the HTML? It sounds like your JS is loading before the HTML, which causes `document.getElementById("btn")` to fail because the HTML part of the page hasn't yet loaded.

Comment: if(document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value == 0 ){
// do your logic here 
}

Comment: `display.value` is incorrect - a `DIV` does **not** have a value property - you need to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` and also the clickhandler is assigned to a `submit` button so you also need to stop the default action using `event.preventDefault()` within the callback

Comment: I fixed the TypeError issue by shifting the script link from the top to bottom of HTML. @kmoser

Comment: Also changed div display to `<input id="display" type="text" readonly="true" />` and added `event.preventDefault()` to stop reload on click. @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks

Comment: so, is your problem now solved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP stated in a comment that their problem was solved by the comments.